# mysql PDO ON DELETE CASCADE - not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have seen my question may already have an answer, and "in mysql, on delete cascade not working" seems to be more similar..... but I can't see anything advised on that post working for me.

The problem is, when I delete a recipe, I want that its attachment gets also deleted (well, step by step, at the moment I am just trying to remove it from mysql table, not from the folder where it is stored).

After I post here a similar question but regarding how to create mysql trigger, I set the foreign key, and on delete cascade, so I though, when a recipe gets delete, the attachment as well, but it happens absolutely nothing to the attachment.... What am I doing wrong?

Next to each recipe I have a button to delete it:

```
echo '<a class="toLink" href="delete_recipe.php?id=' . $recipe['id'] . '" title="delete recipe"  onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this recipe?\');">Delete recipe</a>';
```

In delete_recipe.php:

```
<?php require 'includes/functions.php';

 $recipeId = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);     
      if(delete_recipe($recipeId) == true) {
         header('Location: index.php');
         exit;
      } else {
           $error_message = "Could not delete recipe";
      }
```

In functions.php:

```
function delete_recipe($recipe_id = ':recipe_id') {
          include 'db_connection.php';
    try {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM recipes ";
        $sql .= "WHERE id =:recipe_id ";
        $sql .= "LIMIT 1";

        $results = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $results->bindParam(':recipe_id', $recipe_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if($results->execute()) {
      echo '1 row has been removed';     
    }

    $conn = null;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
        return false;
    }

    return true;  
}
```

I think I have set the foreign key and "delete on cascade" properly..... if I do:

show create table recipes:

```
| recipes | CREATE TABLE `recipes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `attachment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `chef_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_recipes_attachments1_idx` (`attachment_id`),
  KEY `fk_recipes_chefs1_idx` (`chef_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_recipes_attachments1` FOREIGN KEY (`attachment_id`) REFERENCES `attachments` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_recipes_chefs1` FOREIGN KEY (`chef_id`) REFERENCES `chefs` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

show create table attachments:

```
| attachments | CREATE TABLE `attachments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attachment_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Any idea why it does not remove the attachment from the attachments table that belongs to the recipe I am deleting?

Thank you

Comment: ["The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the *child* table"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: I would also guess that the MySQL-error log would balk at this, and give you a hiccup which would shed some light...

Comment: Matt Gibson, can you clarify me that? so, in recipes I have an attachment_id, that belongs to the primary key in the attachments table, so should I put this id on the attachments table as foreign key??!!?!!!

Comment: it does not display errors.... it deletes de recipe, and the attachment stays there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your foreign key relationship backwards. The `attachments` table should have a `recipe_id` column, and that should be a foreign key to `recipes`.

```
CREATE TABLE `attachments` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `attachment_path` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `recipe_id` INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`recipe_id`) REFERENCES `recipe` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The way you did it, deleting an attachment would delete the recipe.

Comment: but..... but..... in attachments I have attachments for ingredients, recipes, methods..... I can't put a recipe_id because not all of them have one :S

I am unexperienced, don't take me wrong, I believe if you said I've done it wrong, I just don't understand it, because then what... do I need a different table for attachments that are not for recipes? :S

Comment: If you want `ON DELETE CASCADE` to work, you need to have separate tables for each type of attachment, e.g. `recipe_attachments`, `ingredient_attachments`, etc. Also, your schema allows a recipe to have only one attachment.

Comment: You can keep your arrangement, but instead of `ON DELETE CASCADE` you can use a trigger that deletes the attachment when deleting or updating the recipe.

Comment: gosh, it's so difficult to learn mysql!!!!!!

Well, that's the intention, each recipe has only one image

oK.... i am going to see how I restructure this....

Thank you

Comment: oH! I have read about this trigger but I couldn't work out why it wasn't working either.... I am going to see what can I do.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just put `image_path` directly in the `recipes` table? What do you gain by putting it in a separate table?

Comment: honestly? I don't know.... I have been told I should keep tables simple.... and create lots of table with different indexes....

Comment: If you have other information about attachments, that makes sense. But if it's just a single column, and you need to use complicated code to keep them in sync, it's not worth it.

Comment: well, the point of this project is just to get comfortable working on databases.... so I guess, it is just for learning. 
One more thing, if I want to include the trigger in a function would this be correct?
  $sql = ' CREATE TRIGGER image_before_delete_recipe';
        $sql .= ' AFTER DELETE ON `recipes`';
        $sql .= ' FOR EACH ROW';
        $sql .= ' DELETE FROM attachments WHERE OLD.id = :attachment_id';
        $sql .= ' LIMIT 1';
        $sql .= ' END';

I mean.... do I do it as a normal query?

Comment: You don't normally put triggers in your scripts. You create the trigger once, when you're creating the tables. The trigger runs automatically.

Comment: let's say the attachments table has another column for "description", and I add a brief description of the attachment ^^

Comment: gosh, why do I want to cry? so.... if I don't create it within my scripts.... where do I create it? in mysql I add straight away "CREATE TRIGGER image_before_delete_recipe AFTER DELETE ON `recipes` FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM attachments WHERE OLD.id = :attachment_id LIMIT 1 END" ???